# Monitoring data flow between Android Framework and App

Tags: android

I need to know how we detect the event of an Android app making a request to the Android Framework for sensor data. Also, if it is possible the Android Framework responding to the said request. I am trying to create a service that will be able to log this information for security or privacy purposes. Is this possible? What is the ideal way to go about it? If it is not possible, do we know why not? Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to create a service that will be able to log this information for security or privacy purposes

I fail to see how spying on application activity regarding sensors will be "for security or privacy purposes".

> Is this possible?

You are welcome to build your own ROM mod that has a revised version of Android, one that contains security vulnerabilities that would allow an app to monitor the sensor requests and responses between another app and the OS. Or, your ROM mod can do the logging directly, through an altered version of the framework.

Otherwise, no, this is not possible from an ordinary SDK application. I do not have enough experience with root-requiring frameworks like Xposed to know whether this is possible using them, though, again, that would require root.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The reason I say it is for privacy purposes is that, I want to provide the users with report of what is happening on their phones. What they would do with such a report? That is something I still have to figure out. Its for a study that I am doing about Android privacy and security.